# How to Pinvoke IronPython on Linux

Tags: linux, mono, pinvoke, ironpython

I'm trying to pinvoke a C function from IronPython 2.6 on Ubuntu 10.10.  I've used an example from the IP distribution as my model.  However, the C code throws "StandardError: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

I've tried several approaches, but none of them work.  Here's my code:

pinvoke_test.h

```
extern void pinvoke_this(const char*);
```

pinvoke_test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pinvoke_test.h"

void pinvoke_this(const char *b)
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("file.txt","w+");
    fprintf(file,"%s", b);
    fclose(file);
}
```

pinvoke_test.py

```
import clr
import clrtype
import System

class NativeMethods(object):

    __metaclass__ = clrtype.ClrClass

    from System.Runtime.InteropServices import DllImportAttribute, PreserveSigAttribute
    DllImport = clrtype.attribute(DllImportAttribute)
    PreserveSig = clrtype.attribute(PreserveSigAttribute)

    @staticmethod
    @DllImport("pinvoke_test.o")
    @PreserveSig()
    @clrtype.accepts(System.Char)
    @clrtype.returns(System.Void)
    def pinvoke_this(c): raise RuntimeError("this should not get called")


def call_pinvoke_method():
    args = System.Array[object](("sample".Chars[0],))
    pinvoke_this = clr.GetClrType(NativeMethods).GetMethod('pinvoke_this')
    pinvoke_this.Invoke(None, args)

call_pinvoke_method()
```

The object file is compiled by "gcc -c pinvoke_test.c -o pinvoke_test.o".  I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I'd suggest getting the full stack trace using -X:ExceptionDetail when running from ipy.exe.  Just knowing the exception text isn't so useful.  You might also have better luck using the ctypes library as it's a more Pythonic way of talking to C libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be the cause of you problem, but the pinvoke signature appears wrong. You C function takes a char*, not a char.

1. This maps to a string in a pinvoke signature. You may need to specify the CharSet to ensure correct marshalling, depending on the platforms you are targeting. See http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries#Strings
2. This change will mean your 'args' variable needs adjusted as well. You want the string "sample", not the first character.
3. Side note: The char type in C# corresponds to a 2-byte character, not a byte.